# Create on Android a Context Menu when selecting an Item from a Popup Menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, popupmenu

I am developing simple application similar to this one

[image: Application with Popup Menu]

Now, I would like to show a Context Menu (as extra options, see example below) when selecting **only** element `One`.

[image: Example of Context Menu]

The main problem I am facing right now is that I have no idea how and where to register the context menu ([registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View))). What should be the view in this case?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative to Context Menus by using [List Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList). This way is much easier that the one I considered.

Answer (score 1):

**use this simple code in Kotlin**

```
val wrapper: Context = ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popup)
        val popup = PopupMenu(wrapper, holder.binding.imgMenu)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.walk_in_patient_menu)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
            override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                when (item?.getItemId()) {
                    R.id.check_id ->
                        return true
                    else -> return false
                }
            }

        })
        popup.show()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes